# maven java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, slf4j, m2eclipse

Hi I'm getting this error in eclipse running maven using m2eclipse,
same error happens with any maven functionality  (install, clean, ect.)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap; from class com.google.inject.internal.Annotations$AnnotationChecker
at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations$AnnotationChecker.<init>(Annotations.java:104)
at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations.<clinit>(Annotations.java:122)
at com.google.inject.Key.ensureRetainedAtRuntime(Key.java:362)
at com.google.inject.Key.strategyFor(Key.java:354)
at com.google.inject.Key.get(Key.java:222)
at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ParameterKeys.<clinit>(ParameterKeys.java:28)
at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.DependencyAnalyzer.<init>(DependencyAnalyzer.java:92)
at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ElementAnalyzer.<init>(ElementAnalyzer.java:87)
at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule.configure(WireModule.java:74)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:230)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:136)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:477)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:203)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:400)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:207)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

the console points towards slf4j as the last constituent

```
constituent[39]: file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.5.1.20150109-1819/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
```

My projects maven depends on guava-17.0 and junit-4.10

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a [bug](https://github.com/google/guice/issues/846) which was fixed in October 2014. Upgrading Guice (and Guava with it) will solve the problem.

Comment: Guice is a dependency on your project. If you added it manually, then download a newer version and replace it, if you added it via Maven, then you need to update your POM, similar with Gradle, etc. It depends on your way of managing your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

- Seems like having a classloader issue with the version of guava that you are Using . for Quick Info go: [**Here**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6007)
- some issues mainly because of clashes between guava versions (15.0 in the driver vs 13.0.1*).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to latest guava using maven or download the jar and it in your build path and add these lines in your weblogic.xml to deploy using your updated guava java .this worked for me.

Check Resolved issue [here](https://connectopensource.atlassian.net/browse/GATEWAY-3360)

```
  <wls:prefer-application-packages>

        <wls:package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.stax2.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.*</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>org.bouncycastle.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and when I changed the jdk version to be 7 instead of 8 the issue disappeared.