# Error on migrate richfaces version 3.3.3 to 4.3.3

Tags: richfaces, migrate

I'm starting the migration from richfaces version 3.3.3 to 4.3.3 and found the following error when publishing the application.

```
cannot Deploy MA-Client
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap; from class org.richfaces.resource.ResourceLibraryFactoryImpl. Please see server.log for more details.
```

I saw the server log and found

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
Source Document: jndi:/server/MA-Client/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler': javax.faces.FacesException: org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler
```

I have a maven project, with jdk 8 and payara 5 server

Comment: `AjaxViewHandler` is not a part of RichFaces 4. Find where it is used, chances are you don't need it.

Comment: I removed from the faces-config the item 'org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler', but the 'com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap...' error continues

Comment: Might be the same issue as this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32528042/1818198, check your Guava dependencies.

Comment: I added the guava-19.0 and guice-4.0 libraries, but the error continues